# How can I assign pointer member with long string?

Tags: c++, pointers

When I did the practice below to erase my pointer member and assign new value to it.

```
(*pMyPointer).member.erase();
(*pMyPointer).member.assign("Hello"); // Successfully
```

Than I tried more...

```
(*pMyPointer).member.erase();
(*pMyPointer).member.assign("Long Multi Lines Format String"); // How to?
```

If the long multi lines string can't quote by double quoter, how to handle it. Thank you.

Comment: What's the question? Where's the problem?

Comment: Am I right to assume you want to know how to write a string literal with line breaks in it? What's that got to do with pointers?

Comment: Maybe he had a gut feeling there's a better way to access a member inside a pointer, and subtly asked for a comment about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ multiline string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135841/c-multiline-string-literal)

Comment: I see, he wants some kind of "block" delimiter. Wrong language...

Comment: No need to call `erase` before `assign`.

Comment: @egrunin, Sorry for my poor english. :-)

Comment: @Nano: I meant **C++** is the wrong language, it doesn't do what you want, where some others might.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really have no clue what you are trying to ask. Maybe this:

```
(*pMyPointer).member.assign("Long Multi Lines Format String"
                            "more lines that will be"
                            "concatenated by the compiler");
```

Or did you mean line breaks like this:

```
(*pMyPointer).member.assign("Long Multi Lines Format String\n"
                            "more lines that will be\n"
                            "concatenated by the compiler");
```

Answer (score 2):

Line breaks in string literals are `'\n'`:

```
"This is a string literal\nwith a line break in it."
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean passing a very long string constant as a parameter, in which case C++ does the string-merging for you: `printf("hello, " "world");` is the same thing as `printf("hello, world");`

Thus:

```
(*pMyPointer).member.assign("Long Multi Lines Format String "
       "and here's more to the string "
       "and here's more to the string "
       "and here's more to the string "
       "and here's more to the string "
       "and here's more to the string ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is is how to create a multi-line string.

You can easily do it with:

```
(*pMyPointer).member.assign(
    "Long Multi Lines Format String" \
    "Long Multi Lines Format String" \
    "Long Multi Lines Format String"
 );
```

You'll have to add a \n to the string if you want to return. Otherwise it's going to stay on the same line.