# String literals without having to escape special characters?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, escaping, string-literals

Is there a string literal form in Objective-c that does not require escaping special characters? In other words, I'm looking for an equivalent to the Python triple quote.

I'm trying to put some HTML into an `NSString`, and would like to avoid having to escape the quotes from all the HTML attributes.

Comment: You could use single quotes in your HTML to avoid having to escape them.

Comment: In C++11 you can do this.  See [my answer][1] to a [similar question][2].  This you require in your case Objective-C++11.  It should work though.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135841/c-multiline-string-literal/5460235#5460235
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135841/c-multiline-string-literal

Comment: Just a note, "triple-quote" has been implemented since Swift 4, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47567770/897465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no equivalent to the triple-quote; string literals must always use escapes for special characters.

Perhaps the best thing to do would be to put your HTML into a file separate from your source, then create the string using [`-[NSString initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJHHCFJ) (or the related `initWithContentsOfURL:...`).

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 you can do this.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135841/c-multiline-string-literal/5460235#5460235) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135841/c-multiline-string-literal).

For this you require in your case Objective-C++11.  It should work though in gcc.

```
const char * html = R"HTML(
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
   <TITLE> [Python-Dev] Triple-quoted strings and indentation
   </TITLE>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY BGCOLOR="#ffffff">
  blah blah blah
 </BODY>
</HTML>
)HTML";

int
main()
{
}
```

g++ -std=c++0x -o raw_string raw_string.mm at least compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, unfortunately not ... there's some great info on string literals in obj-c here:
http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/07/objective-c-tuesdays-string-literals.html

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this now:

This feature has been implemented since Swift 4. Read more about it here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0168-multi-line-string-literals.md

You can do:

```
let author = "Im the author!"
let x = """
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
        <book id="bk101" empty="">
            <author>\(author)</author>
            <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
            <genre>Computer</genre>
            <price>44.95</price>
            <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
            <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
        </book>
    </catalog>
"""
```