# Heredoc-like syntax from strings in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there an alternate syntax for strings in Swift ? I need to copy/paste blocks of text including lots of quotes and escaping them each time is kind of a pain.

I'm looking for something like PHP's [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax, or Python's triple quoted strings. Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091233/swift-split-string-over-multiple-lines), but I don't care about newlines, I just need it to ignore quotes and backslashes.

Here's a concrete example of the disaster I'm facing right now :

```
let pattern = "(?:\["(this|is|a|pain|to|escape|properly)+)",0(?:,\[10\])?\])" // that makes me sad
let json = "window.google.ac.h(["this",[["is",0],["even",0],["worse",0]],{"q":"...","k":1}])" // that makes me cry
```

Thanks.

Comment: Would it make any sense to put them in a string resource or a plist file instead? That's often a good solution to this category of problem.

Comment: @MattGibson well, I'm just using this in playgrounds for debugging, I'm not sure if they can even access resources. For the production app the data comes from a web service so it isn't an issue.

Comment: You can [read resource files from a playground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245916/how-can-i-read-a-file-in-a-swift-playground)—you can store the resource files alongside the playground file and load things from there just fine. Of course, I don't know how much of a pain that would be for your particular workflow!

Comment: @MattGibson that would indeed break my workflow badly... for right now I'll just deal with the manual escaping but I'd love to see a solution to this.

Comment: You should write a Services Menu extension that will escape selected text, or whatever's in the clipboard. I'm sure other people would like to see one :)

Comment: @MattGibson I'd love to do so, but my Swift experience is... well... nonexistent so that's going to be tough. :/

Comment: Well, you don't need Swift to do it :D I just [hacked something up quickly](http://gothick.org.uk/2014/12/10/a-quick-hack-to-quote-swift-strings-in-a-playground/) that might help you, and also give you an example of how to build a Services menu :D

Comment: @MattGibson awesome, thanks ! And I said Swift because a quick search for "service menu" brought me to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000101-SW1) and it looks long and scary. :o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As with Objective C, there's no syntax for this in the language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025004/string-literals-without-having-to-escape-special-characters). Strings just have to be escaped, at the moment, at least. The alternative is to load the string from a resource file.

I'd raise a bug report with Apple on this one; it would be helpful for the language, more so than with Objective C, for just the reasons you're finding: Swift can be executed more dynamically, in a playground/REPL, so there's more reason to want to paste arbitrary stuff into string constants while you're playing.

Addendum: As an exercise in quick hacking, I just knocked up a quick and dirty Services Menu item in Automator for quoting strings in place in a playground. That's beyond the scope of this Stack Overflow answer, but [I documented it on my blog](http://gothick.org.uk/2014/12/10/a-quick-hack-to-quote-swift-strings-in-a-playground/).

Comment: There's a reason you haven't mentioned for why heredoc syntax would be good; at present, constructing a long string by "adding" strings together in code brings Swift completely to its knees. The _only_ way I've found to load a paragraph of complex text into a variable is to get it from a resource file. Doing it in source code isn't just clumsy - it literally breaks the source code, by blowing up the compiler.

Comment: Yup, we need more people to file radars on this. Swift's poor handling of large strings is a massive problem and needs to be fixed. Apple is obviously aware of it, but more complaints will result in a quicker solution. Which of these do you prefer? https://gist.github.com/abhibeckert/b12e19a85c4806296c7e

Comment: @matt I'd not actually needed to do that, so I hadn't noticed the compiler creaking under the weight. But there have been times in pretty much any language I've used that lacks a heredoc syntax where I've really been annoyed by that lack. I'll put "file a radar" on my todo list for tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

This feature was added to Swift in 2017. ([SE 0168 Multi-Line String Literals](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-170))

[Swift Documentation: Welcome to Swift: Simple Values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.html#ID461) says:

> Use three double quotation marks (`"""`) for strings that take up
>   multiple lines. Indentation at the start of each quoted line is
>   removed, as long as it matches the indentation of the closing
>   quotation marks. For example:
>
> ```
> let quotation = """
> I said "I have \(apples) apples."
> And then I said "I have \(apples + oranges) pieces of fruit."
> """
> ```

According to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397374/swift-three-double-quotes#comment75794516_44397374) on [Swift three double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397374/swift-three-double-quotes), "This is brand new to Swift 4 and Xcode 9."

For more details, see [Swift Documentation: Language Guide: Strings and Characters: String Literals: Multiline String Literals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID564).

Answer (score 3):

Swift doesn't support it, but [C++11 does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#New_string_literals). And we can easily import it to Swift, as `NSString`s.

StringConst.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSString *const STR_PATTERN;
extern NSString *const STR_JSON;
```

StringConst.mm:

```
#import "StringConst.h"

NSString * const STR_PATTERN = @R"""((?:\["(this|is|a|pain|to|escape|properly)+)",0(?:,\[10\])?\]))""";
NSString * const STR_JSON = @R"""(window.google.ac.h(["this",[["is",0],["even",0],["worse",0]],{"q":"...","k":1}]))""";
```

<Target>-Bridging-Header.h:

```
#import "StringConst.h"
```

AnySwift.swift:

```
println(STR_PATTERN)
println(STR_JSON)
```

---

Added:

To use this in Playground, you have to create a Framework project, and Playground file in it.

[image: sceenshot]

Comment: Sadly, this isn't much help in a playground, as far as I can see. Let's hope Swift catches up to C++11 faster than C++ did...

Comment: I think this can still be a useful technique, and it's definitely a valid answer to the original question.

Comment: @MattGibson we can still use that in Playground :)

Comment: Unfortunately this is a bit too much work just to set this up, isn't practical for quick debugging when you add a playground to an existing project. And it would break my workflow if I need to switch back and forth between files just to edit the strings.