# boost::python long/structured docstrings

Tags: c++, boost-python

I have a c++ function wrapped for python exposure. I use boost::python for this purpose. For the same, I wish to have a structured doctoring, which will look very much like

```
    some text here.....

    Parameters:
    p1 ...
    p2 ...
    p3 ...

    Returns:
    R1 ...
```

Now, my problem is, when I place the above in the docstring placeholder

```
     def("wrapFunName", cppFunc, "PLACEHOLDER")
```

compiler (clang) throws me an error of `missing terminating ' " ' character`. Does it mean that I can not wrap the long doctoring with booth::python and I have to write it continuously? I thought c++/c would always be free-form languages :(.

Thanks in advance,

Nikhil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that although you are writing code to be used from Python, you're still writing C++, so you're bound by the rules of C++ syntax. C++ doesn't allow multiline string literals in quite the same way as Python does. In particular, it doesn't allow bare line breaks in strings, so when the compiler reaches the end of the line without finding the end of the string, it rightly complains, as you've observed.

You can use any of [several techniques for getting multiline strings in your C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1135841/33732). For example, you can insert the line breaks explicitly with `\n`, or you can escape the line breaks with `\` at the end of each line. Those techniques and more are demonstrated in the answers to the linked question.

Here's an example of the first method. Note the `\n` at the end of each line. C++ automatically joins consecutive quoted string literals into a single value, which is why there are no operators between the lines.

```
def("wrapFunName", cppFunc,
    "some text here.....\n"
    "\n"
    "Parameters:\n"
    "p1 ...\n"
    "p2 ...\n"
    "p3 ...\n"
    "\n"
    "Returns:\n"
    "R1 ...")
```

Comment: multiline string literal was the thing I missed :(... thanks!