# \n not working after I hit the enter button

Tags: c++, enter

I am writing a `cout` statement in C++, but the statement is very big so I pressed enter so that I can start from next line (not want to write full long statement in one line). It was working fine but if `\n` (new line) is the first character after hitting the enter as you can see the second line of code it was not working. So I just want to ask is there any way to start your code from the next line (continuing the previous line of code) after hitting enter.

```cpp
cout<<"\nChoose the operation you want to perform :
\n1. To insert a node in the BST and in the tree \n2";
```

Comment: the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135841/c-multiline-string-literal/1135862) show ways to define multi-line strings =

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ multiline string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135841/c-multiline-string-literal)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can this way:

```
std::cout << "\nChoose the operation you want to perform:\n"
             "1. To insert a node in the BST and in the tree\n"
             "2. ...\n";
```

You cannot have a string on one line that doesn't end with a `"`, but two properly terminated strings in a row are concatenated. So `"foo" "bar"` becomes `"foobar"`. Having `"foo"` and `"bar"` on separate lines is fine.

As others have mentioned, C++11 supports raw string literals, which do allow strings to be spread out over multiple lines, and avoids having to write `\n`:

```
std::cout << R"(
Choose the operation you want to perform:
1. To insert a node in the BST and in the tree
2. ...
)";
```

Comment: You're missing an `<<` between your strings.

Comment: @Chipster No, [they're not](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/254984/30872).

Comment: @GSerg Bizarre, I could have sworn I've **never** been able to compile something like that before, but now I can't seem to create an example of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a multiline string literal like

```
const char* s1 = "\nChoose the operation you want to perform:\n"
                     "1. To insert a node in the BST and in the tree\n"
                     "2. some text here";
```

our you can use raw string literals without any quotes or new line literals (cf, for example, [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) at cppreference.com):

```
const char* s1 = R"foo(
Choose the operation you want to perform:
1. To insert a node in the BST and in the tree
2. some text here)foo";
```

These two `s1`-variants are equivalent. Then write

```
std::cout << s1;
```

Comment: You're missing the `\\` for line continuation in your 1st example.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I don't think so: String literals placed side-by-side are concatenated at translation phase 6 (after the preprocessor). That is, "Hello,"  " world!" yields the (single) string "Hello, world!"

Answer (score 0):

You have the option:

```
std::cout << "\nSome text,\n"
             "\nsomething else\n";
```

(which was originally proposed by @G. Sliepen)

I would rather prefer using `std::endl`.

The code would look like:

```
std::cout << std::endl << "Some text," << std::endl <<
             std::endl << "something else" << std::endl;
```

Yet another option is to use [`R` prefix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) (which is used to avoid escaping of any character):

```
std::cout << R"(
Some text,
something else

)";
```

My favourite is the last one.

Comment: It's a common misconception that `std::endl` is more cross-platform. It is in fact equivalent to `"\n"` plus a flush of the stream, which makes it bad for performance. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n

Comment: @G.Sliepen Thank you! I'm wrong about it. I'll edit the answer so as not to delude others.