# Multiline string literal in Ada

Tags: string, ada, multiline, literals

How can I create a string in Ada containing newlines, whose definition also has those newlines?

I've tried with 0..2 backslashes at the end of the line, but none of that compiles:

```
   usage_info : String := "\
This should be the first line
and both the definition and the output
should contain newlines.";
```

In PHP this would be:

```
<<<BLOCK
1
2
3
BLOCK;
```

[In C++ this would be:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135841/c-multiline-string-literal)

```
const std::string s = "\
1
2
3";
```

[In C#, it would be:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c-sharp)

```
const string s =
@"1
2
3";
```

Comment: If you can define "newline" as a Character or sequence of Characters then of course you can define a String value containing it. If all of the Characters are graphic characters then you can define a String literal contining it. I suspect that any such definition will be very non-portable.

Answer (score 8):

From what I know, Ada , like Java, does not support multiline literal.
The only thing I see is something like this:

```vhdl
usage_info : String := "This should be the first line" & CR & LF
                     & "and both the definition and the output" & CR & LF 
                     & "should contain newlines.";
```

Of course, you need to *with* and *use* *Ada.Characters.Latin_1* to make these constants visible.

Comment: See [ARM 2.6(7)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-2-6.html#p7), "An end of line cannot appear in a string_literal".

Comment: @SimonWright Thanks for pointing out the small note on the ARM, now I'll be able to say without hesitation that this is not supported :)

Answer (score 2):

A complement to Frédéric Praca answer:

Depending on your needs, you can use `ASCII` package instead of `Ada.Characters.*` (such as Latin_1, Latin_9, Wide_Latin_.. etc.). `ASCII` can not be `with`'ed since it is not a package, so you'll have to prefix everything (or define "aliases" using `renames`)

```
declare
    flex : constant String := "Foo" & ASCII.CR & "bar" & ASCII.LF;
    flux : constant String := "Foo" & ASCII.CR
                            & "bar" & ASCII.LF;
begin
    -- do stuff
    null;
end;
```

*One could define a custom `&` operator to use it as a new line insertion point. But ...  how useful is it ?*

```
function Foo (Left, Right : String) return String renames "&";
function Boo (Left : String; Right : Character) return String renames "&";

function "&" (Left, Right : String) return String is begin
   return Foo (
               Boo (Left, ASCII.LF),
               Right);
end "&";

Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Foo" &
                     "bar");
```

Comment: Well, there are still people who use and develop using older Ada versions in which ASCII may have some sort of sense or justification. The `&` operator part is still relevant.

Comment: Nice idea (about the operator)! Why not using another operator? ```with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure LF is
  function "*" (Left, Right : String) return String is (Left & ASCII.LF & Right);
begin
  Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Foo" * "bar");
end;```