# Multi-line wide string constant that allows single line comments in C++

Tags: visual-c++, comments, c++17, c-strings

This question of how to break up a (wide) string constant along multiple lines in code has been asked and answered multiple times on this platform ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135841/c-multiline-string-literal), for example). I have been using the following approach to declare a static wide string in the class definition itself:

```
#include <Windows.h>    
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
    public:
        static constexpr WCHAR TEST[] = L"The quick brown fox" \
                                        L"jumped over the" \
                                        L"lazy dog!";
    /* ... */
};

int main ()
{
    wprintf(Test::TEST);
    return 1;
}
```

However, this approach does not work very well if you want to start commenting each line of your multi-line string. The only way you can achieve this is if you stick a multi-line comment in between the string and the backslash (`\`) like so:

```
class Test
{
    public:
        static constexpr WCHAR TEST[] = L"The quick brown fox" /* A comment */\
                                        L"jumped over the" /* Another comment*/\
                                        L"lazy dog!";
    /* ... */
};
```

If you put a comment after the backslash (`\`), then a compiler error is raised. This means, you cannot use the traditional single line comment (`//`) with this method. As a matter of fact, if you put a single space after the backslash (`\`), then a compiler error is generated.

My question is as follows, **is there a way to declare a wide string over multiple lines where you can use single line comments (`//`) to comment each line?**

I am idling looking for something like this (similar to Java):

```
static constexpr ... = L"The quick brown fox" +  // A little comment here...
                       L"jumped over the" +      // A little comment there.
                       L"lazy dog!";
```

I understand things are incredibly different in Java (i.e. namely everything is an object), but I am just giving this as an example of what I am after.

Comment: In your first snippet, you don't need the backslashes. Adjacent string literals are concatenated, even if they're on separate lines. (This doesn't answer  your question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply drop the backslashes:

```
    static constexpr WCHAR TEST[] = L"The quick brown fox" // a comment
                                    L"jumped over the"     // another comment
                                    L"lazy dog!";          // yet another comment
```

Comments are replaced by space characters in translation phase 3. Adjacent string literals are concatenated in translation phase 6.

Comment: Yeah, I took your comment and gave it a shot and it work with single line comments. I appreciate it. Although, I do have a question, were you the one that down voted my question? Was there something specific you thought merited a down vote?

Comment: @CodeDoggo: No, it wasn't me. Only a guess, but maybe someone objected to your referring to `\` as "forward slash" and downvoted rather than fixing it.

Comment: Yeah, that was a mix up in my head. It was an honest mistake - I appreciate the catch as you had in your edits.