# How do we print multi-line content in c++ in an native and elegant way?

Tags: c++, io

I am trying to print stuff like this like an exercise:

```
  *
 ***
*****
 ***
  *
```

and I have been using c++ to print every line in a separate statement. It can pass the tests all right.

However, I have learnt in python that we can do something like this:

```py
s = """
  *
 ***
*****
 ***
  *
"""
print(s)
```

and it does the job neatly.
So I have been wondering: Is there an elegant equivalent in c++?
The searching I have used all need using `\n` or `std::endl` as line breaks, which I do not want to do.

Comment: the duplicate is an old question, hence the most up to date [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5460235/4117728) is not the accepted or highest voted one

Comment: fwiw the point of such exercises is to practice loops. Rather than using a raw string literal, I suggest to use the `std::string` constructor that takes a character and number of times to repeat, which can help a lot in such exercises without avoiding all the loops

Comment: You can use [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use multiline string literals, like this :

```
#include <iostream>

const char *s= "  *  \n"
               " *** \n"
               "*****\n"
               " *** \n"
               "  *  \n";

int main()
{
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note : in C++ nowadays I prefer using std::string_view.