# How to write multiline inline assembly code in GCC C++?

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

This does not look too friendly:

```
__asm("command 1"
      "command 2"
      "command 3");
```

Do I really have to put a doublequote around every line?

Also... since multiline string literals do not work in GCC, I could not cheat with that either.

Comment: [Can I write multiple Assembly instructions on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27685548/995714)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I always find some examples on Internet that the guy manually insert a tab and new-line instead of \t and \n, however it doesn't work for me. Not very sure if your example even compile.. but this is how I do:

```
asm volatile(           // note the backslash line-continuation
   "xor %eax,%eax          \n\t\
    mov $0x7c802446, %ebx  \n\t\
    mov $1000, %ax         \n\t\
    push %eax              \n\t\
    call *%ebx             \n\t\
    add $4, %esp           \n\t\
    "
    : "=a"(retval)        // output in EAX: function return value
    :
    : "ecx", "edx", "ebx"   // tell compiler about clobbers
  // Also x87 and XMM regs should be listed.
 );
```

Or put double quotes around each line, instead of using `\` line-continuation.  C string literals separately only by whitespace (including a newline) are concatenated into one long string literal. (Which is why you need the `\n` inside it, so it's separate lines when it's seen by the assembler).

This is less ugly and makes it possible to put C comments on each line.

```
asm volatile(
    "xor %eax,%eax          \n\t"
    "mov $0x7c802446, %ebx  \n\t"
    "mov $1000, %ax         \n\t"
    "push %eax              \n\t"  // function arg
    "call *%ebx             \n\t"
    "add $4, %esp           \n\t"  // rebalance the stack: necessary for asm statements
  : "=a"(retval)
  :
  : "ecx", "edx", "ebx"    // clobbers.  Function calls themselves kill EAX,ECX,EDX
  // function calls also clobber all x87 and all XMM registers, omitted here
);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that's more or less what I have seen in examples, however, it is still just "less ugly" for sure! Takes my motivation away from writing asm.

Comment: So less-but-still-ugly! Thanks! :)

Comment: The alternative to `\t\n` is semicolon to separate instructions.  `\t\n` is better because the resulting asm output won't be a mess.  It's typical to use `"insn \n\t"`  `"insn2 \n\t"` etc, and let string concatenation work, though, instead of ending each line with a backslash.

Comment: The very ugly way is also the will-unexpectedly-not-work way, though the less ugly way also suffers from this problem.

Answer (score 6):

**C++ multiline string literals**

Interesting how this question pointed me to the answer:

main.cpp

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cinttypes>

int main() {
    uint64_t io = 0;
    __asm__ (
        R"(
incq %0
incq %0
)"
        : "+m" (io)
        :
        :
    );
    assert(io == 2);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -o main -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra main.cpp
./main
```

See also: [C++ multiline string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135841/c-multiline-string-literal)

GCC also adds the same syntax as a C extension, you just have to use `-std=gnu99` instead of `-std=c99`:

main.c

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    uint64_t io = 0;
    __asm__ (
        R"(
incq %0
incq %0
)"
        : "+m" (io)
        :
        :
    );
    assert(io == 2);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gcc -o main -pedantic -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra main.c
./main
```

See also: [How to split a string literal across multiple lines in C / Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797318/how-to-split-a-string-literal-across-multiple-lines-in-c-objective-c/54576129#54576129)

One downside of this method is that I don't see how to add C preprocessor macros in the assembly, since they are not expanded inside of strings, see also: [Multi line inline assembly macro with strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259732/multi-line-inline-assembly-macro-with-strings)

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, GCC 6.4.0, binutils 2.26.1.

**`.incbin`**

This GNU GAS directive is another thing that should be in your radar if you are going to use large chunks of assembly: [Embedding resources in executable using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158900/embedding-resources-in-executable-using-gcc/36295692#36295692)

The assembly will be in a separate file, so it is not a direct answer, but it is still worth knowing about.