# Multi line inline assembly macro with strings

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to implement a macro (`"MY_MACRO"`), which stores a string preceded by a 32 bit integer number in a certain section `("my_section")`.
Example: `MY_MACRO(200, "my first string %u %x")`;

Here are the options I tried and the problems I'm facing with. I would appreciate any help.
(`gcc 4.7.3. MIPS cpu`)

### Option A:

```
#define MY_MACRO(_num, _string)\
asm volatile(".pushsection .my_section");\
asm volatile(".byte %0, %1, %2, %3" : : "i"((_num >> 24) & 0xFF), "i"((_num >> 16) & 0xFF), "i"((_num >> 8) & 0xFF), "i"(_num & 0xFF)); /* Store the number */ \
asm volatile(".ascii " #_string);\
asm volatile(".popsection");
```

Compile error (it doesn't occur for each usage of the macro):

```
c:\Temp\ccpDEDnt.s: Assembler messages:
c:\Temp\ccpDEDnt.s:1024: Warning: .popsection without corresponding .pushsection; ignored
```

I think the reason is a compiler optimization which changes the instructions order (although each asm instruction is volatile, the compiler is allowed to change the order).
Q: Is there any way to disable the compiler optimizations just for the scope of these lines without `#pragma`?
This issue led me to find a solution in which the four asm instructions are unified.

---

### Option B:

```
#define MY_MACRO(_num, _string)\
asm volatile(".pushsection .my_section\n\t" \
             ".byte %0, %1, %2, %3\n\t" \
             ".ascii " #_string "\n\t" \
             ".popsection" \
             : : "i"((_num >> 24) & 0xFF), "i"((_num >> 16) & 0xFF), "i"((_num >> 8) & 0xFF), "i"(_num & 0xFF));
```

Compiler errors:

```
foo.c:733:13: error: invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letter
foo.c:733:13: error: invalid 'asm': operand number out of range
```

Since the string includes the percent sign (%), the compiler interprets it as an asm operands.

---

### Option C:

```
#define MY_MACRO(_num, _string)\
asm volatile(".pushsection .my_section\n\t" \
             ".byte %0, %1, %2, %3\n\t" \
             ".ascii %4\n\t" \
             ".popsection" \
             : : "i"((_num >> 24) & 0xFF), "i"((_num >> 16) & 0xFF), "i"((_num >> 8) & 0xFF), "i"(_num & 0xFF), "X"(#_string));
```

Here I tried to pass the string as an operand. I don't even know if it's feasible.
I didn't manage to compile this code.

Comment: Without macro requirement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666013/how-to-write-multiline-inline-assembly-code-in-gcc-c

Answer (score 0):

**Option B** is the right way, however you will need to double all percent signs (`%`) occurring in your string because that's interpreted as an operand placeholder in the inline asm.

If you don't particularly care about ordering or inlining, you could also let `gcc` handle it for you:

```
struct mystruct
{
    int num;
    char string[0];
};

#define MY_MACRO(_num, _string)\
{ static struct mystruct entry __attribute__ ((section (".my_section"))) = { _num, _string }; }
```

Comment: I cannot double all percent signs because the code is compiled to many platforms. Some of them need to get the string in the regular format. I tried the gcc solution you suggested and got this compile error:  "error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long"

Comment: That's just a warning, because of the zero-length array, but it should work fine (it does for me). You can disable and reenable that warning in the macro.