# x86-64 assembly online, with an IDE such as https://www.mycompiler.io/new/asm-x86_64

Tags: assembly, ide, x86-64

Could anyone help me write the equivalent of the program below so it works on the online IDE at  https://www.mycompiler.io/new/asm-x86_64?  I am a teacher and want to show my students so real working assembly so they stop thinking Little Man Computer is real.  I just don't have time right now to work it out for myself!

```
section .text
    global main
    extern printf           ; the C function to be called
main:
 
    mov eax, 45
    mov ebx, 55
    add eax,ebx
    push eax
    push message
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    ret
 
message db "Value = %d", 10, 0
```

Comment: Depending on ABI some arguments, even for variable-argument functions (like `printf`), might be passed using registers

Comment: This won't be quite as easy as that online tool does not allow you to link in the libc.  Perhaps chose a different one that does?  E.g. you can try https://gcc.godbolt.org.

Comment: Happy to use godbolt.  I didn't see a way of actually running the assembly code on that one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a number in assembly NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194141/how-to-print-a-number-in-assembly-nasm)

Comment: @Tortoise Select assembly as the source file format.  Note that this is GNU assembly, not NASM assembly.

Comment: @fuz: NASM is also supported on godbolt, but as Tortoise says you can't execute an asm program; "Run the compiled output" is grayed out.

Comment: @NateEldredge A strange restriction, indeed.

Comment: [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) has code that work with raw x86-64 Linux system calls, which is apparently necessary because the IDE you picked doesn't seem to allow linking libc.  e.g. `extern exit` lets `call exit`  it assemble but not link, as a quick test: `undefined reference to 'exit'`.

Comment: @fuz: perhaps Godbolt GCC in C++ mode with `asm(R"(  ... .globl main; main: ... )" )` at global scope, with `-masm=intel`?  [How to write multiline inline assembly code in GCC C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3666013).  Pretty nasty and clunky, and doesn't afford any ability to single-step with a debugger, so that's a terrible option for students.  https://tio.run/ has NASM.

Comment: https://www.onlinegdb.com/ has asm, but only GCC (GAS), not NASM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.mycompiler.io/new/asm-x86_64 apparently doesn't link libc for asm, so you can *only* use Linux system calls directly (via `syscall`), not libc functions like printf.

https://www.onlinegdb.com/ has asm, but only GCC (GAS), not NASM.  Still, you can use `.intel_syntax noprefix` to get GAS's MASM-like Intel syntax.  **Crucially, it does have a working GDB setup that lets you single-step your asm and see register values.**  This is nearly essential for learning asm: many kinds of mistakes lead to exactly the same error (segfault, or no output), and these are mistakes the assembler won't diagnose.  Learning asm without a debugger is like trying to build a robot while blindfolded (or other colourful analogies).

Seeing exactly what each instruction did is *exactly* how you should be thinking about asm, especially when trying to understand why your program didn't do what you hoped.

---

If you *did* want to use that specific IDE (mycompiler.io) without libc, [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894) has code that turns an unsigned integer into a decimal ASCII string and feeds it to an x86-64 Linux `write` system call with `rax=1` / `syscall`.

`extern exit` lets `call exit` assemble but not link, as a quick test: `undefined reference to 'exit'`.

There's also https://tio.run/ which has NASM and FASM, as well as GAS.  FASM allows making 32-bit code via having FASM make an executable directly (`format ELF executable 3`) instead of a `.o` which TIO.run expects to be able to link into a 64-bit executable.  I've used that to test some code-golf answers ([like this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203155/30206)) where I specifically wanted 32-bit mode, not 64-bit, so I could use `dec edi` on a pointer without needing a REX prefix.

---

I notice that you're using a 32-bit stack-args calling convention for your attempt to call printf.  That's not how the x86-64 System V ABI works ([What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-and-user-space-f)), so make up your mind whether you want to teach 32-bit code (which has a simpler but worse calling convention, and almost everything can be 32-bit), or x86-64 where normal code often takes advantage of 32-bit operand-size and the implicit zero-extension to 64-bit.  And where args are passed in registers, to system calls with a similar calling convention to function calls.

related: 32-bit [Hello, world in assembly language with Linux system calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61519222/hello-world-in-assembly-language-with-linux-system-calls) with `int 0x80` system calls and lots of explanation.

Also, you don't want to use `int 0x80` in 64-bit code: [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)