# Can I add my own assembly file/instructions to a godbolt project?

Tags: c++, assembly, clang, compiler-explorer

Just like the title suggests. Say, I want to do this with a [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) project:

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int test_111();

int main()
{
    int r = test_111();
    
    std::cout << "result=" << r << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and then in `asm1.asm`:

```
.code

test_111 PROC

    ; 64-bit assembly
    xor eax, eax
    inc rax

    ret

test_111 ENDP

END
```

Trying it under "x86-64 clang" (any version).

But I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Any suggestions?

PS. The goal is to inject my own assembly instructions into the output.

---

EDIT:

After a suggestion in the comments, I tried the `asm volatile` key words, but it simply adds whatever gibberish I put in there into the assembly output:

[image]

Comment: For starters that is `masm` syntax assembly so it won't work.

Comment: do you know how to get it working outside of godbolt?

Comment: Godbolt has an "IDE mode" (aka Tree) which lets you use multiple files with cmake. The Templates are a good starting point.

Comment: Or just use `asm volatile( .... )` inline with your code

Comment: @perivesta that's probably what I need. But would it work for a 64-bit build? Can you give an example?

Comment: IDK why you think 64-bit or not would change whether GNU C inline asm works.  Maybe you're thinking of MSVC?  Their inline `asm{}` support was so clunky and brittle (e.g. not supporting functions with register args) that they abandoned it for targets other than 32-bit x86.  But that's a problem with MSVC, not inline asm in other compilers like GCC, Clang, or ICC, and you want GNU C inline asm syntax anyway if you want to put whole functions at global scope.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, I'm definitely MSVC biased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Tree mode, you can set up a CMake project with multiple files, including asm:

[Godbolt Link](https://godbolt.org/z/9d8d6j3Ya)

To make it work, I had to enable `nasm` support in the `CMakeLists.txt` file and manually set the path to the assembler

```
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER /opt/compiler-explorer/nasm-2.14.02/bin/nasm)
enable_language(ASM_NASM)
set(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "${CFLAGS} -x assembler-with-cpp")
```

Comment: Oh wow, interesting. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

> I tried the asm volatile key words, but it simply adds whatever gibberish I put in there into the assembly output:

Yes, GNU C inline asm just prints extra text into the asm.  And the Godbolt compiler-explorer's default mode of operation is to just show you the compiler's asm text output.  (Clang is different: unlike GCC, it has a built-in assembler, so it does require your asm statements to assemble.)

In the dropdown, you can select "compile to binary object" to compile to a `.o` and show you disassembly of that, or to compile to a linked executable (including a dummy `main` if your code doesn't have one) and disassemble that with `objdump`.  This will feed the output of the C->asm compiler (`cc1` or `cc1plus`) through the assembler, so you will get errors if there's a problem.

---

Don't use Basic Asm (no constraints) inside functions, except with `__attribute__((naked))` in which case Basic Asm is the *only* thing you can put there.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended

**You can use Basic Asm at *global* scope, though, almost exactly like a separate `.s` file, using the [GNU assembler's](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html) `.intel_syntax noprefix` which is MASM-like other than directives.**

You can get examples of valid syntax from [looking at GCC and Clang output for simple C/C++ functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) on Godbolt.  (The asm source in your question uses MASM directives like `.code` and `foo PROC`.  You'll need to change that to just using a label.  Since it's in the same compilation unit as the caller, you don't need `.global test_111`)

```
// compile this with -masm=intel; the default is att
asm(R"             # multi-line string literal
.text
test_111:
    # 64-bit assembly
    # lea rax, [RIP + main]     # example of its addressing-mode syntax
    xor eax, eax
    inc rax
    ret
");


#include <iostream>

extern "C" long long test_111();
// your asm uses RAX, which would be pointless if you only return a 32-bit type

int main()
{
    long long r = test_111();

    std::cout << "result=" << r << '\n';  // endl sucks and clutters the asm
    return 0;
}
```

You need to put `-masm=intel` on the compiler command line; normally compiler-explorer only passes it for builds that are going to stop at the `.s` output to show that to the user, not for the separate build of an executable to run.  But `xor eax,eax` isn't valid in AT&T syntax; that would be two memory operands and an ambiguous operand-size.

[See it on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:10),source:%27//+compile+this+with+-masm%3Dintel%3B+the+default+is+att%0Aasm(R%22(+++++++++++++%23+multi-line+string+literal%0A.text%0Atest_111:%0A++++%23+64-bit+assembly%0A++++%23+lea+rax,+%5BRIP+%2B+main%5D%0A++++xor+eax,+eax%0A++++inc+rax%0A++++ret%0A)%22)%3B%0A%0A%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aextern+%22C%22+long+long+test_111()%3B%0A//+your+asm+uses+RAX,+which+would+be+pointless+if+you+only+return+a+32-bit+type%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++long+long+r+%3D+test_111()%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22result%3D%22+%3C%3C+r+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B++//+endl+sucks+and+clutters+the+asm%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.996973627323825,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2+-Wall+-masm%3Dintel%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:64.74808963874622,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g132,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2+-Wall+-masm%3Dintel%27,overrides:!(),source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:0,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:64.74808963874622,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:35.25191036125379,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:61.00302637267618,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) with both "execute the code" checked for the compiler-output pane, and a separate "executor" pane, both needing `-masm=intel`.

Re: using `R"( ... )"` in C++, see *[How to write multiline inline assembly code in GCC C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666013/how-to-write-multiline-inline-assembly-code-in-gcc-c)*

Comment: Thanks. Is there a comprehensive manual for the AT&T disassembly syntax btw?

Comment: @c00000fd I think Sun may have written one at one point.  If you prefer Intel syntax, disassemble with it, though.  GNU tools all support options like `objdump -drwC -Mintel` or GDB `set disassembly-flavour intel`.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dDependent.html documents x86-specific stuff for GAS, including Intel vs. AT&T, and AT&T syntax design bugs: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dBugs.html .  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info has sufficient details to figure out the AT&T for any instruction.

Comment: Thanks. I'm kinda confused about the mnemonic suffixes that AT&T asm uses: b=8bit, w=16bit, l=32bit, q=64bit, t=80bit. Sometimes I see them, other times I don't, but yet sometimes there's more than one suffix used in one mnemonic. What's the rule there?

Comment: @c00000fd: A suffix is optional if a register implies the operand-size.  Does the tag wiki not say that, or at least link a question about it?  (If not we should fix it)  There are never two suffixes, but sometimes a mnemonic itself includes a size, like with the AT&T versions of `movzx`, such as `movzb` (the byte-source version of movzx, often used with 32-bit operand size as `movzbl`.) [What does cltq do in assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/a/45386217) shows movsbw / movswl equivalents.  And [What does the MOVZBL instruction do in IA-32 AT&T syntax?](//stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/64468695)