# How to make a new line in this C printf code?

Tags: c

```
printf("%c Trying to forget someone you love is like trying to remember someone you never knew \n\n",3);
```

become like in vb.net:

```
printf("%c Trying to forget someone you love is like trying to" & 
"remember someone you never knew \n\n",3);
```

We add the next string on new line.... How to connect the string in C language.

Comment: Just leave out the ampersand. Two juxtaposed string literals will become one. (This won't print a newline, though, and paste "to" and "remember" together in your case.)

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797318/how-to-split-a-string-literal-across-multiple-lines-in-c-objective-c) for a more detailed answer, which also gives an alternative.

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm newbie in C....

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

```
printf("%c Trying to forget someone you love is like trying to "
       "remember someone you never knew \n\n",3);
```

String literals can be written like that with multiple quoted parts. It is still just one string. That way can have indentation and comments in between.

---

```
printf("%c Trying to forget someone you love is like trying to \
remember someone you never knew \n\n",3);
```

You can split string literal by having backslash as *last* char in line. There will ne no newline in the resulting string, if you want that use `\n\` at the end. Also if you indent the 2nd line, that whitespace will go into the string, usually not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the strings after each other without any operator in between.

```
printf("%c Trying to forget someone you love is like trying to "
       "remember someone you never knew \n\n", 3);
```

It will be treated like one long string by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write

```
printf("%c Trying to forget someone you love is like trying " 
       "to remember someone you never knew \n\n",3);
```

Two juxtaposed string literals will become one.