# Compile Windows NT command line code loop with check function in c/c++

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, c++, c

The Batch file code are as following:

```
:continue
start myfile.exe 
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq myfile.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "myfile.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto :exit
goto :continue
exit:
```

I tried to write in c and compiled it.

```
include < stdlib.h >
int main()
{
  system(":continue
start myfile.exe 
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq myfile.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "myfile.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto :exit
goto :continue
:exit");
  return 0;
}
```

But it is not working. What is going wrong?

Comment: "_It is not working_" is the worst error description I can think of.

Comment: Your [multiline C string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/797351/107625) seems to be invalid.

Comment: no , only single code is working : #include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main()  {
    system("system.exe "); 
    return 0; 
  
  }

Comment: Why would you wrap batch in C??? It is almost straight forward rewrite your code in C, instead of wrapping. Regarding "obfuscation", compiling system calls with string arguments will for sure store string data in your compiled .exe which can easily be seen with a `type` command.

Comment: OK SIR. but I don't know HOW to do that. my  main purpose is that:          
Check myfile.exe file is running or not.,if running then exit and if not running then run myfile.exe.                                                                  sound very simple but one here help me with code. can you SIr please.

Comment: Yeah... you're going to have to learn C. You can't just paste batch into a C file and call it ported. You have to actually write the equivalent C code.

Answer (score 2):

The [`system()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem) function is to used to run individual binaries. Your batch script is not an individual binary - it is a list of Batch Command Processor instructions.

The easiest solution I can see is to save your batch script into a [.BAT file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) and then use the system command like this:

```
system("C:\Windows\cmd.exe /s C:\path\to\your\file.bat");
```

Comment: sir,my main purpose is to hide my bat file code and run in exe so after all my research and after compiling a  simple batch code in C ,I thought it is possible to compile whole code in C .

Comment: Then you need to use more than one system() commands - probably one fo r each command in your BAT script.

Comment: PLZ SEE THIS http://textuploader.com/dc2df

Comment: This is getting funny...

Comment: MY OBJECTIVE: Check myfile.exe file is running in "window system task list" or not,if running then exit and if not running then run myfile.exe.