# How do I wrap up the line c++

Tags: c++

I have a very long line:

```
const string a_string = "a long string with \" .. with \" again ... ... ";
```

Now this string goes really long, how do I wrap up the line in an elegant way? I tried just break line but it doesn't work. I am actually not sure if this is a IDE problem or compiler problem... Please help!

Comment: The linked question is for C/Objective-C, but the solution is exactly the same as in C++. Possible duplicate of [How to split a string literal across multiple lines in C / Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797318/how-to-split-a-string-literal-across-multiple-lines-in-c-objective-c)

Comment: Do you want the line breaks to appear in the string itself (i.e. visible to the program's user) or do you want the string to be a single-line string as far as the user is concerned, but have it appear as multiple lines in your IDE?

Comment: Do you need line wrap in a GUI, Console or something else?

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
const string a_string = "a long string "
                        "with \" .. with \" "
                        "again ... ... ";
```

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld [It works just fine](https://ideone.com/3jVzIT).  When two string literals are separated by only whitespace, the compiler merges them together in the final executable

Comment: Is it IDE-dependent?

Comment: I don't see a reason why it won't work. This is valid syntax in C++. Here is a working example https://ideone.com/i3c3Qj

Comment: What IDE are you using? You say in your question it may be an IDE or compiler problem but don't let on what you're using

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld throw a bone to those that follow and mark this question as answered.