# How to store a private key in string literal in C?

Tags: c, string, openssl

How to store a private key in string literal in C?

e.g.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOgIBAAJBANuwDJCXuv/FszouyCcDNIn6++/8EtdVpzvLKpqLdK/fq6Y3bIjD
6fPVCNwANeJsSHKexi4qPkBpZ8/C0Ssnp48CAwEAAQJAHtDmIk42W/R2fJ3dU6Oe
dhBv0K0SU4RfTgLkugL/3j+GIQCiFXBkfO/eG6J8vQlOQaGbK7Zu6bSnCoCdiDmR
sQIhAPysf1AIbRoQGO6HYtAoTUOMlih7dyh4O3jKCqQUa60XAiEA3pRju0/0g2JK
bdSct/kqii1o+RydH79WCnKVgVvulEkCIFdbRADliOLT4erFv/H7nQrXliqU1ROW
zejq4VbtAHUtAiBRP5OkRYx5BUEsFGdc1MyNggQGo0ZL13ld+PPQM7HEWQIhAIU1
InlMgmqV1GzEXsAwRH5RH2zEqAe9mKkU7SZWT0rI
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

1. Can I remove newlines in each line?
2. What is the best method to define multiple lines string literal in C?

Comment: It is alreay in a file. What do you mean by in C?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string literal across multiple lines in C / Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797318/how-to-split-a-string-literal-across-multiple-lines-in-c-objective-c)

Comment: Just quote each line, e.g. `char *myliteral = "..." "..." "...";` (where the spaces represent newlines)

Comment: @ShiDoiSi I will compute the digest and signature from a plaintext with the private key.

Comment: Try `const char *key = "MIIB...bIjD" "6fP......6Oe" ... "Inl...0rI";`

Comment: It's a bad idea to embed sensitive information such as passwords or private keys in an executable file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disregarding the security concerns associated with such a "solution", you could do this:

```
const char* key =
    "MIIBOgIBAAJBANuwDJCXuv/FszouyCcDNIn6++/8EtdVpzvLKpqLdK/fq6Y3bIjD"
    "6fPVCNwANeJsSHKexi4qPkBpZ8/C0Ssnp48CAwEAAQJAHtDmIk42W/R2fJ3dU6Oe"
    "dhBv0K0SU4RfTgLkugL/3j+GIQCiFXBkfO/eG6J8vQlOQaGbK7Zu6bSnCoCdiDmR"
    "sQIhAPysf1AIbRoQGO6HYtAoTUOMlih7dyh4O3jKCqQUa60XAiEA3pRju0/0g2JK"
    "bdSct/kqii1o+RydH79WCnKVgVvulEkCIFdbRADliOLT4erFv/H7nQrXliqU1ROW"
    "zejq4VbtAHUtAiBRP5OkRYx5BUEsFGdc1MyNggQGo0ZL13ld+PPQM7HEWQIhAIU1"
    "InlMgmqV1GzEXsAwRH5RH2zEqAe9mKkU7SZWT0rI";
```

The pointer `key` now points to the private key which is embedded in the executable. It doesn't include the newlines because those string literals are automatically concatenated at compile time, no matter what whitespace is between them.

It has been said already, but I'd like to reiterate that something like that shouldn't be done with any keys and data that matters.